# non empty set with empty interior is countable at most

Tags: calculus, general-topology

A is non empty set of R and set of interior points of A is empty. Then A is countable at most.

How to (dis)prove it?

Empty interior for non-empty set implies that A consist of isolated points. I cannot imagine uncountable (i.e. infinite) set of isolated points, that's why I tend to think that the statement is true. Could you help me to prove?

Comment: As mentioned, it is not true that a set with empty interior has only isolated points.  However, it is true that a set $A$ consisting only of isolated points must be countable.  One way to see this: if $x$ is an isolated point of $a$, we can find an interval $(p_x, q_x)$ with rational endpoints that contains $x$ but no other point of $A$.  Then the map taking $x$ to $(p_x, q_x)$ is a one-to-one map from $A$ to the countable set $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, which means $A$ is countable.

Comment: More generally, this is based on the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is [second countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_countable).

Answer (score 5):

take all non-rationals. there's uncountably many of them yet their interior is empty

Comment: The moral is: sets (even sets in the real line) can be more complicated than you think!

Comment: @mm-aops. Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem. also, @Sanki - it's not true that empty interior means that the set consists of isolated points

Comment: @GEdgar, unfortunately, yes :)

Comment: @Sanki: Fortunately, yes.

Comment: @mm-aops, how so?

Comment: well, an isolated point $x_0$ of a set $S$ is a point for which exists a ball $B$ containing $x_0$ but no other point of $S$, while a set has an empty interior if it doesn't contain any open ball. you can clearly see that non-rationals have empty interior (because rationals are dense in $R$) while every non-rational $w$ is a limit point of the set of all non rationals (consider the sequence $w + 2^{-n}$).

Answer (score 3):

The [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is uncountable, and its interior is empty.

Comment: An explanation is probably in order. I doubt the OP knows what the Cantor set is or how to prove its interior is empty.